# File backup for deploying a rails app with capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, backup, capistrano

I am deploying my rails 4 application with capistrano onto an Ubuntu 14.04 server. This is the `deploy.rb` I am using currently:

```
server 'ip', port: port, roles: [:web, :app, :db], primary: true

set :repo_url,        'git git'
set :application,     'appname'
set :user,            'user'
set :puma_threads,    [4, 16]
set :puma_workers,    0

set :pty,             true
set :use_sudo,        false
set :stage,           :production
set :deploy_via,      :remote_cache
set :deploy_to,       "/home/#{fetch(:user)}/apps/#{fetch(:application)}"
set :puma_bind,       "unix://#{shared_path}/tmp/sockets/#{fetch(:application)}-puma.sock"
set :puma_state,      "#{shared_path}/tmp/pids/puma.state"
set :puma_pid,        "#{shared_path}/tmp/pids/puma.pid"
set :puma_access_log, "#{release_path}/log/puma.error.log"
set :puma_error_log,  "#{release_path}/log/puma.access.log"
set :ssh_options,     { forward_agent: true, user: fetch(:user), keys: %w(~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub) }
set :puma_preload_app, true
set :puma_worker_timeout, nil
set :puma_init_active_record, true  # Change to false when not using ActiveRecord

## Defaults:
# set :scm,           :git
# set :branch,        :master
# set :format,        :pretty
# set :log_level,     :debug
# set :keep_releases, 5

## Linked Files & Directories (Default None):
set :linked_dirs,  %w{bin log tmp/pids tmp/cache tmp/sockets vendor/bundle public/uploads}

namespace :puma do
  desc 'Create Directories for Puma Pids and Socket'
  task :make_dirs do
    on roles(:app) do
      execute "mkdir #{shared_path}/tmp/sockets -p"
      execute "mkdir #{shared_path}/tmp/pids -p"
    end
  end

  before :start, :make_dirs
end

namespace :deploy do
  desc "Make sure local git is in sync with remote."
  task :check_revision do
    on roles(:app) do
      unless `git rev-parse HEAD` == `git rev-parse origin/master`
        puts "WARNING: HEAD is not the same as origin/master"
        puts "Run `git push` to sync changes."
        exit
      end
    end
  end

  desc 'Initial Deploy'
  task :initial do
    on roles(:app) do
      before 'deploy:restart', 'puma:start'
      invoke 'deploy'
    end
  end

  desc 'Restart application'
  task :restart do
    on roles(:app), in: :sequence, wait: 5 do
      invoke 'puma:restart'
    end
  end

  before :starting,     :check_revision
  after  :finishing,    :compile_assets
  after  :finishing,    :cleanup
  after  :finishing,    :restart
end


namespace :sake do
  desc "Run a task on a remote server."
  # run like: cap staging sake:invoke task="a_certain_task"
  task :invoke do
    on roles(:all) do |h|
      execute "cd #{fetch(:deploy_to)}/current && bundle exec rake #{ENV['task']} RAILS_ENV=#{fetch(:rails_env)}"
    end
  end
end

# ps aux | grep puma    # Get puma pid
# kill -s SIGUSR2 pid   # Restart puma
# kill -s SIGTERM pid   # Stop puma
```

I had an issue in this file so that my `shared/public` folder got overwritten and I lost a lot of uploaded images. Due to this loss I am now considering to implement some way of creating a backup outside of the application directory on the server for uploaded files.

Is it possible to create some kind of automated routine that copies the current shared folder to a save space on the server before capistrano deploys the new version?

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you probably want to hook into Capistrano's `deploy:started` step to perform your backup before the new version is deployed.

Define a task that performs your backup:

```
task :backup_shared_public do
  on roles(:all) do
    # Very basic backup technique. YMMV!
    execute "mkdir -p ~/public_backups" 
    execute "cp -Rp #{shared_path.join('public')} ~/public_backups/#{Time.now.to_i}"
  end
end
```

And then tell Capistrano to execute it before every deploy:

```
after "deploy:started", "backup_shared_public"
```